# Getting a crash due to NSXPCDecoder didHideZoomSlider on iOS 8 after taking a picture

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Any idea what this crash is all about?In my iOS app I am using an ImagePickerController to launch the camera.After I take a few images it crashes saying this:-

[NSXPCDecoder didHideZoomSlider:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Here is the code that I am using

```
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]
                                                      init];
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
#else
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
#endif
    imagePickerController.editing = YES;
    imagePickerController.delegate = (id)self;
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Did you resolve above issue? Please share your comment. Please let me know if you resolve this or not.

Comment: Looks like an Apple Bug.Need to file a Radar for the same.